# How can I create a camera session?

Tags: android-camera2

I'm trying to create a new camera session for my Android application.

I have tried using Googles sample codes from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic.

But the codes do not work on my device:

```
    /**
     * Creates a new [CameraCaptureSession] for camera preview.
     */
    private fun createCameraPreviewSession() {
        try {
            val texture = textureView.surfaceTexture

            // We configure the size of default buffer to be the size of camera preview we want.
            texture.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height)

            // This is the output Surface we need to start preview.
            val surface = Surface(texture)

            // We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
            previewRequestBuilder = cameraDevice!!.createCaptureRequest(
                    CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW
            )
            previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface)

            // Here, we create a CameraCaptureSession for camera preview.
            cameraDevice?.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, imageReader?.surface),
                    object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

                        override fun onConfigured(cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession) {
                            // The camera is already closed
                            if (cameraDevice == null) return

                            // When the session is ready, we start displaying the preview.
                            captureSession = cameraCaptureSession
                            try {
                                // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
                                previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                                        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)
                                // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
                                setAutoFlash(previewRequestBuilder)

                                // Finally, we start displaying the camera preview.
                                previewRequest = previewRequestBuilder.build()
                                captureSession?.setRepeatingRequest(previewRequest,
                                        captureCallback, backgroundHandler)
                            } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
                                Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
                            }

                        }

                        override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
                            activity.showToast("Failed")
                        }
                    }, null)
        } catch (e: CameraAccessException) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString())
        }

    }
```

When I run my app, I'm getting the following errors:

```
E/Legacy-CameraDevice-JNI: LegacyCameraDevice_nativeGetSurfaceId: Could not retrieve native Surface from surface.

E/CameraDeviceGLThread-1: Received exception on GL render thread: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Surface had no valid native Surface.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are not waiting for the Surface to be ready before passing it to your session in this line:

```
cameraDevice?.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(surface, imageReader?.surface)
```

If you backtrack, you'll see that the Surface comes from a TextureView:

```
val texture = textureView.surfaceTexture
```

You need to wait until the Surface is ready. For that, you should attach a SurfaceTextureListener and wait for `onSurfaceTextureAvailable` to be called. Then it's safe to retrieve and use the Surface for your camera session.